# direct SQL rather than curser and loop

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a requirement where we have to calculate some of the daily values based on the frequency that is being passed to SP. So basically we go a number of days behind based on the time-frequency passed within SP and calculate values till today.

Within the stored procedure, we have written curser and used a temp table to do this. Wanted to know if there is any way possible to avoid using curser or temp table here? Currently, if tie frequency is much longer like the last 20 years or so, looping through the entire 20 years of data one by one and calculating for each day is too costly and it takes time. Do we have any faster way of doing this rather than looping through each of the records? We can precalculate this data as well but in this case, it doesn't make sense as we don't know what will be the input time-frequency which will define how many days back to go and start our initial calculation from that day.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
tmptable(someId VARCHAR(8), someDate DATE, pct DECIMAL(30,3), someValue DECIMAL(30,3));


OPEN curls;
FETCH curls INTO isomeId,  isomeDate, ipct;
    INSERT INTO db_fdsloader.tmp_tblGrowthOfTenK(someId, someDate, pct, someValue) SELECT isomeId, isomeDate, ipct, 100;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curls INTO isomeId,  isomeDate, ipct;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tmptable(someId, someDate, pct) SELECT isomeId, isomeDate, ipct;
    SET  @value = @value + (@value * (pct/100));
    UPDATE tmptable SET VALUE = @value WHERE someDate = isomeDate;

END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE curls;
```

We, later on, use this into some joining AS below.

```
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(t1.NavDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS navDate,
        t3.GrowthTenK AS tenkValue,
        t1.ChangeNavPercent AS tenkPercentChange
    FROM
        table1 t1 
    JOIN 
        tmptable t3 ON t3.someId = t1.someId AND t3.someDate = t1.someDate
    WHERE 
        t2.tk = iTk
```

;

Comment: Is `pct/100` supposed to be `ipct/100`? If not, where does `pct` come from?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want the *query* to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `INSERT` as a single query without a cursor. You can reassign the `@value` variable in the query.

```
SET @value = 0;

INSERT INTO tmptable (someId, someDate, pct, someValue)
SELECT t1.*, @value := @value + @value * pct/100
FROM (
    your query
) AS t1;
```

Replace `your query` with the query that your cursor was connected to.

You could actually do this without the temporary table, by joining with the above `SELECT` as a subquery in your final query. But creating the temporary table would allow you to add an index on `(someId, someDate)`, which should speed up the join.

Comment: Thank you for feedback on this. The above-mentioned solution works almost but not for the least record where value has to be 0. For the first record, value should be default 1000 and then it will calculate value for daily frequency using pct as well. For the first daily value, it should be 1000 but in your above query, it calculates value for the first record as well which shouln't be true.

Comment: Change the initial value of @value

Comment: yes. I have done that change already but if the default value is 1000 than value of the first record for first date has to be 1000 as well. It is second record onwards, value gets calculated using previous value and pct value as shown on previous calculations. How do we keep the first value without another insert for just first record only and second insert for second record onwards? is my explanation clear?

Comment: please suggest if there is any better way of doing the above requirement?

Comment: I don't really understand what the original procedure intends for the first row. You don't show how `@value` is initialized in the procedure.

Comment: It is basically initialized with 100 so first record should have value with 100 and calculated values on second record onwards.